# Android Slide Menu as Home

Tags: android, menu

is it possible to create a menu similar to the one that appears in home screen of Android?
[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes what you are looking for is called [Sliding Drawer](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

Comment: Really helpful hint and answer, Actually i am also wanting to implement this concept for "sliding panel menu" but dont know the concept that this is known as "Sliding Drawer" but your answer made my life..